How to define a normal Markov algorithm (NMA) to swap two ternary numbers separated by the symbol "^"?
I'm trying to write a normal Markov algorithm in an emulator to swap two ternary numbers separated by the symbol "^". For example, for input "120^210", the result should be "210^120".
I have tried these rules:
^0 -> 0@^
^1 -> 1@^
^2 -> 2@^
@^0 -> 0@^
@^1 -> 1@^
@^2 -> 2@^
@^ -> ^
^->@
@0 -> ^0
@1 -> ^1
@2 -> ^2
@ -> ^

But it didn't work correctly; I just get "120210^".
